# How can we perform real schur decompositon (Youla decomposition) for a real and anti-symmetric matrix in Julia language?

Tags: julia, linear-algebra

I want to transform a real and anti-symmetric matrix into block diagonal form. I wonder if there is a function in julia which can achieve it?
[image: real schur decomposition]

Answer (score 0):

Since it is possible to get the eigenvalues from the original matrix using the standard `eigen`, the result can be constructed. This might be buggy in the current form, but it is a proof-of-concept:

```
using Random
Random.seed!(123)

A = randn(6, 6)
B = A - A'
# B will be the matrix we want to decomposition on

egv = eigen(B).values
F = [(iseven((i+j)÷2) || (abs(i-j) != 1)) ?
  0.0 : sign(j-i)*abs(egv[max(i,j)]) 
  for i in axes(B,1), j in axes(B,2)]
```

Now `F` looks like:

```
6×6 Matrix{Float64}:
  0.0      4.72892   0.0      0.0       0.0       0.0
 -4.72892  0.0       0.0      0.0       0.0       0.0
  0.0      0.0       0.0      1.28596   0.0       0.0
  0.0      0.0      -1.28596  0.0       0.0       0.0
  0.0      0.0       0.0      0.0       0.0       0.634589
  0.0      0.0       0.0      0.0      -0.634589  0.0
```

and has the same eigenvalues.
`eigen` is quite optimized, so this method should be competitive. Note that for odd sized matrices, a real eigenvalue also participates and this has to be treated separately (perhaps it might be wise to pair the values in `egv` explicitly).